# Clean model of a JList java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I try to fill a JList but first remove existing elements to avoid repeated records.
LLenarGrid that method call on a button to show that is to display objects in arraylist and JList but if I have 5 elements and give twice the button I get 10 doubles me as if I did not clean up the model

I leave my method, if I could help? or that I'm doing wrong, Thanks

```
public void LlenarGrid()
{

    listapersonas.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
     DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel)listapersonas.getModel();
     listModel.removeAllElements();
     for (clsPersona d : personas) {
        listModel.addElement(d.RetornaPersona());
    }
    listapersonas.setModel(listModel);
    listapersonas.clearSelection();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what LLenarGrid is, or if it is a typo; nor what call the method is referring to. Please resolve these issues because otherwise it's difficult to know what your question is asking.

Comment: LLenarGrid that method call on a button to show that is to display objects in arraylist and JList but if I have 5 elements and give twice the button I get 10 doubles me as if I did not clean up the model

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [mcve]

Comment: If the code you presented is what exhibits the problem then I'm inclined to guess that you're getting duplicates in `personas`, and from there putting them into your `JList`.  You assign a new (empty) model to `listapersonas`, and then you *also* explicitly clear the model (and then redundantly set the same model again), so I don't see any way that this produces a list whose elements do not match `personas` 1:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to set the model to list multiple times.

you can remove all element using below which you are already doing.

```
model.removeAllElements();
```

As suggested by John Bollinger  check the personas List.

Comment: are right, it was going to fill the arrayList but did not give the array.clear ();
Thank you